# Virtual multiple inheritance and pointers

Tags: c++

Given the following class hierarchy:

```
class A {
int x;
public:
A(int X) : x(X) {}
void setX(int x) { this->x = x; }
};



class B : public virtual  A {
int y;
public:
B(int X, int Y) : A(X), y(Y) {}
};

class C : public virtual A {
int z;
public:
C(int X, int Z) : A(X), z(Z) {}
};

class D : public C, public B {
public:
D(int x, int y, int z) : A(x), C(x,z), B(x,y) {}
};
```

and the following main:

```
int main (void)
{
D x(2,3,4);
A* temp1 = &x;
B* temp2 = &x;
C* temp3 = &x;
}
```

It seems that temp1,temp2 and temp3 are all pointing to different addresses..
Shouldn't B and C share the same A object?
After all, Every C and B object is ALSO an A so the pointers should "see" the A object first.. no?
In addition , the C pointer contains the X's address.. which is a D object. why?

here is the memory map:

```
&x      0x0036f828 {...}    D *
temp1   0x0036f838 {x=5 }   A *
temp2   0x0036f830 {y=3 }   B *
temp3   0x0036f828 {z=4 }   C *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the way the object is [represented in memory](http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html).

So your object looks like this:

```
+ 0x0036f828
- D
- int z (C)
- int y (B) 
- int x (A)
```

C++ casting just gives the offset of the beginning of the object.
So you can see that the offset is just the size of an integer for classes **A,B,C** (because that's what they contain) and a virtual table for classes **B,C**.
And **D** doesn't have members, so its offset is 0.

Note that the C++ compiler sets the memory layout by the order you actually write the members and base classes.

So if you'd change the order of the base classes in D, then you'll get different results:

```
class D : public B, public C
```

Now **B** will be the first class in the layout after D.

Comment: hehe thanks for that blog.. kinda same question. So I guess C is pointing to X because the first object in D is the C one.

Comment: @Rouki I've found a better example/link edited the answer to contain that link, it explains the memory layout even better, with an exapmle for virtual inheritance. And yes, it's because C is the first base class in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that B and C needs to share the same A object. And that is exactly what would happen here. The address that you're seeing is actually the address of a virtual table that is unique to each class. In the case of virtual inheritance, the virtual table of each class would then have a pointer to the virtual base classes, in this case, object A.

So the virtual table of both classes B and C would have a pointer each pointing to the same address of object A.

Comment: Ok.. and why does temp3 has the same address as X?

Comment: That would be an optimization of the compiler, where classes D and C share the same virtual table. This is usually seen in multiple inheritance where the derived class would use the same virtual table as one of its bases. I have to mention that in this case, it is not really a virtual table, but a virtual base table. A virtual table is similar and used for virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is how things might look if written out using plain structs:

```
struct A {
  int x;
};

struct B {
  A *ap;
  int y;
};

struct C {
  A *ap;
  int z;
};

struct D {
  C c;
  B b;
  A a;
};

int main (void)
{
  D x;
  A* temp1 = &x.a;
  B* temp2 = &x.b;
  C* temp3 = &x.c;
}
```

Since `B` and `C` use virtual inhertiance, they only contain a pointer to the base, and not the actual object.  You can see that since `c` is at the beginning of `D`, they will have the same address.